# Adding second date format to jQuery UI Date Picker is not working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to set the `datepicker` date format like  `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",` and this is because I am getting data from database in this format. Now I want to display any changes of `datepicker` in this format `'DD, d MM, yy'` what I did was

```
 onSelect: function(){
     var formattedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy' }).val();
     alert(formattedDate);
    }
```

but the `datepicker` still returning the data in `"yy-mm-dd"` format. How can I fix this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/8hotr6y3/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the utility function:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, options )

$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )
```

See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1ku4wLzf/5/

**JavaScript**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: new Date('2019-10-31'),
  onSelect: function(dStr, obj) {
    var dt = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", dStr);
    var fdt = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD, d MM, yy", dt);
    alert(fdt);
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks like a great answer. Minor feedback though - there is a preference amongst mods and long-standing readers for succinct, technical writing. On that basis, while it is good that you hope your answer helps, everyone posts answers in the hope that they help, and thus the remark is redundant. In general, editors will remove this sort of thing (though it is true we don't have enough editors for the volume of posts on the site).

Comment: @halfer please site where this preference is documented. I would also be concerned that humanity on a whole may become all too technically succinct in it's overall communication. Yes, we should work to address questions directly and with good technical answers, yet everyone should be allowed to express themselves in a personal manner and flair. I think the world needs more hope in it and I really do not appreciate having my answer edited purely on your personal preferences when the technical aspect is sound.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358730/does-i-had-the-same-issue-count-as-fluff

Comment: Probably not enough votes to be canonical, but worth a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341622/what-sorts-of-edits-should-editors-make-to-posts-and-why

Comment: This one is probably the canonical post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: This answer is helpful, contains thoughts from the founder of Stack Overflow about is "wiki-like" nature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11486

Comment: I think the "we need to be human" argument has been put forward on _Meta_, and largely been rejected, with a minority of opinion from folks who are not active on that site. So, I take it that the majority consensus is that succinct and technical writing is preferred here. You may get away with rolling back, but you can expect people to keep making these edits.

Comment: If you are particularly exercised about keeping your 427 HTH sign-offs, then please ask a question on _Meta_ asking whether it is OK. I think you'll get -100 for it, and that will reflect broadly what I have set out above. That feedback will also indicate that the expectation for technical writing is not my "personal preference", and that my editing is a reflection of the consensus. I hope you feel able to give way in the future.

Comment: @halfer thanks for citing the various posts. I will review them and consider the content.

Comment: @halfer I have read through the posts you shared. The majority of them are in regards to Questions and not Answers, yet I see the parallel you're drawing. If sign-off like elements should not be in questions, they should not be in answers. Finally, in one, I see "*You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning.*" This is part of the selected answer and reviewing your edits, they do not make my answer better, clearer, or more effective. We *are* human and I think my answer is effective, clear, and good with just a tiny personal flair. Is this bad etiquette?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I have never heard, in my ten years here, someone suggesting that answers are exempt from editing. I _personally_ think that once the editing standards are pointed out, that an author should give way, and I am _certain_ the standards I have drawn your attention to apply to answers. "Hope this helps" is, indeed, explicitly mentioned in one of those links.

Comment: As to whether removing conversational/chatty material improves answers, you are probably right that it is subjective. The editor's motivation here is that technical writing is clear and free of cruft, and improving the efficiency of writing (i.e. using fewer words to convey more meaning) is always a good thing. Moderators will generally _prefer_ technical writing, but they also would not want to lose a good contributor. In a minor edit of this kind, an editor probably could not appeal to a moderator to enforce it. I'll leave it with you `:-)`.